# vb.net Regex.Split to return array of words and punctuation without empty strings?

Tags: .net, regex

I want to use `Regex.Split` to get an array consisting of words (ie sequences of "word characters") and any punctuation marks (i.e. "non-word characters"). I don't want any array element to contain letters and punctuation together, I don't want the array to include spaces and I don't want empty strings. Currently I have

```
words = Regex.Split(MyString, "([^\w])")
```

but if I try it against a normal sentence with the odd comma, parenthesis etc. in addition to the words and punctuation marks I want it's returning a bunch of empty strings as well as strings consisting of just a space. Can anyone suggest a Regex pattern that would do the job, or am I going to have to loop through my array and remove the empty strings and space elements subsequently?

Edit: Thanks to the people who have answered but I think I did not explain clearly enough what I am looking for. Given the input string "Hi, Fred!!" (not including the quotes) I want the array to return

```
word(0) = "Hi"
word(1) = ","
word(2) = "Fred"
word(3) = "!"
word(4) = "!"
```

and nothing more. Any ideas? Everything I've tried so far has returned empty strings and/or strings consisting of a space.

Comment: What about numbers like `2.5`? Or URLs, emails. other entities? Also, if you have `my_variable`, do you want `'my', 'variable'` two tokens or `'my_variable'` single token?

Comment: Wiktor these are good questions I hadn't thought of. However, I don't expect these issues to come up in my program as the input text is already limited in scope and curated, besides which the app allows users to correct wrong tokenisation if they see any. It was more the initial heavy lifting I was concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
\w+|[^\w\s]+
```

---

- `\w+`: Matches any word character, between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.
- `|`: Or
- `[^\w\s]+`: Matches any character that is neither a word character nor a space, between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/DTyVpp/1).

---

### Update:

To have the punctuation in different matches, just remove the last `+`:

```
\w+|[^\w\s]
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/uvGY6o/1):

Comment: Depending on the OP's requirements (not clear) `\w+|[^\w\s]` may be desired.

Comment: Thanks Cubix48. I tried your expression in http://regexstorm.net/ (great because it gives you a rundown on the results of a split) and it gives me a long list of empty strings. After a bit of reading and experimentation I came up with   \s+|(\b+[^\w]+)   which is close to what I want, only the punctuation marks are run together and there's an empty string at the end.

Comment: @GERARDLEWIS I understand, it's because ``Regex.Split`` try to cut the text following the matches. You should better use ``Regex.Matches`` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The problem with Regex.Split seems to be that if it finds a character that matches more than one of your criteria it throws in an empty string. There's probably a way to construct the expression to get around this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @GERARDLEWIS There is no such a regular expression that will let you avoid empty strings in `Regex.Split`. Either remove empty items with an additional code, or use `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: Thanks, Cubix48. I tried Regex.Matches and your suggested regular expression gave me exactly the result I was hoping for. Again many thanks.